# R replace first n column value with NA

Tags: r

I have a large set of stock data over a two year period. The data frame is sorted by stock id and date, i.e. first I have all data for one stock and then all data for the second stock and so on. Now I want to replace the first 29 values (rows) in a column with NA for each stock. Is there a simple way to do that?

I have tried to use:

```
aggregate(column~stock_id, data = df, FUN = function(x){x[1:29] <- NA})
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Two things: (1) it's necessary you offer a reproducible example in order to verify every detail in your problem. (2) Every function has to be a return object, I can see that the function that you are specifying inside aggreggate doesn't have any explicit return, maybe thats the problem, but to be sure, do the point (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aggregate` is for summarizing - you end up with 1 row per group. You want the same number of rows, so `aggregate` won't work for you.

I'd use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(stock_id) %>%
  mutate(column = case_when(row_number() < 30 ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ column))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `ave`

```
i1 <- with(df, ave(seq_along(stock_id), stock_id, FUN = seq_along) < 30)
df[i1, setdiff(names(df), 'stock_id)] <- NA
```